# Render wireframes with hidden wires?

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I need to render my models in wireframe (no solid). I first turned to the Wireframe modifier, it works great. Only I can see through to the wires at the back of the model. I need to render only the front-visible wires, otherwise it just clutters the view. Is it possible and how? (No matter if it's BI or Cycles in this case.)

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the Clipping parameters of the Camera?

Comment: I don't think that will work as I have 2 rows of models, one behind the other, so I need to render front-wires of both rows, and hide back-wires of both rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I played some more. And I found an acceptable solution. I use the Wireframe modifier. I set it to solid (don't replace original). I set 2 materials on the object, white and black. Set the solid to white (emission shader) and the wireframe to material offset +1 (meaning black). And I get a nice clean geometry with only visible wires and edges.

Answer (score 5):

Add a Geometry node and use the backfacing information to control the transparency of the object:

[image]

[image]

The inside "backfacing" geometry will be transparent and the "front facing" will use the wireframe.

Comment: Ok, I played with this solution, it seems to work. There is one problem though. All the implicit edges show up. Say I have an N-gon, all the edges within the N-gon show up, which are normally invisible. Is there a cure for this too?

Comment: That is a limit on the cycles wireframe node - it only sees the geometry that is sent to cycles for rendering, which is a triangulated mesh.