# How can I create a faceless sphere?

Tags: mesh, objects

I just want the skeleton of the sphere that you see in 'edit' mode. I need that in normal object mode. This below is what I am roughly trying to create.
[image: wireframe sphere]

Comment: I don't think your image showed up. Can you [edit]https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/108026/edit) your post to include the image?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23616/how-to-render-as-only-wireframe-in-cycles

Comment: Use a wireframe node along with a backfacing node. Like in this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38384/render-wireframes-with-hidden-wires/38387#38387

Answer (score 1):

Use the wireframe modifier. By editing the different parameters, you can create a very similar result to what you are asking about.